# Coding a web page that works in IE8 but breaks in IE11

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, compatibility, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to demonstrate to some folks in a seminar how particular elements (be they html tags, css defined styles or JavaScript behaviors) that were coded to work properly in IE7, also works in IE8, but fails in IE11.

Currently the intranet I'm showing works properly in IE11, but I want to change the code so that it doesn't. In other words, what can I add/change to my code that will allow it to continue rendering correctly in IE8 but breaks in IE11?

Comment: Interesting: you are looking for a way to demonstrate something, but apparently do not actually know what...

Comment: The site I'll be presenting does not show certain malformed elements or quirky behaviors, so yes, I need to "break" the site to demonstrate what is wrong and needs to change to make it work in IE11 or greater.

Comment: There is no point in this: you try to show something you do not have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go thru the list of legacy API removals in IE11 provided in detail in this MSDN documentation:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bg182625%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#legacyAPIs

One example is the use of the attachEvent method which is removed in IE11

Comment: This is excellent... may just be what I'm looking for (reading it over now.) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could write some JavaScript that uses [document.all](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms537434%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), a terrible terrible way to get elements that worked through IE10 but was dropped in IE11.